# MCP2551 to monitor CAN activity without processor

Tags: digital-logic

If I was to connect an MCP2551 to a CAN network and link the TX and RX processor connections would this allow monitoring of any activity on the network as just a 5v pulse train without disturbing the network?

Comment: it is unclear what this means `link the TX and RX processor connections`

Comment: @jsotola my guess OP wants to connect Tx/Rx pins of the transceiver to Rx/Tx pins of the MCU.

Comment: @Maple, the question does not read like that ... it sounds like the OP wants to connect some unknown piece of test equipment because the word `monitoring` was used .... the word `link` needs to be explained by the OP because it could mean different things

Comment: @jsotola Hmm... yes, that "without processor" in the title and "link ... processor connections" taken together do beg for an explanation

Comment: To clarify, if an MCP2551 is simply connected to CAN network with the TX pin unconnected it's logic level could be undetermined therefore a dominant 0 could appear on the CAN and cause conflict. Normally a processor with CAN on board would be connected to the MCP2551 as in a normal CAN node so the software would ensure TX is properly driven. I am assuming that if the TX is connected to the RX pin and no processor is present the data out would always match the data in and leave the MCP2551 invisible to the network. monitoring the TXRX junction externally would then reveal any network activity.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. Table 1-2 in datasheet clearly states that 1 or floating on TX results in bus not being actively driven. Connecting TX to RX will result in immediate bus latch up on the first dominant bit received. If you don't want to disrupt bus traffic all you have to do is leave TX disconnected (or connect it to Vcc) and listen on RX pin, as I already explained to you in the comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, it is possible.

But it would take **very** fast processor to even store raw network traffic, yet alone analyze ("monitor") it. Keep in mind that CAN bitstream cannot be decoded without huge efforts if it does not contain timing information (frame boundaries), so it either has to be processed in real time or you need to insert time-stamps into it.

Letting CAN controller do all this heavy lifting and processing parsed messages is **much** easier. This is exactly how all network sniffers I know of work.

Comment: Actually I don't need to decode any data just need to know somethings happening on the network without disturbing it. I wondered if just pulling TX high to produce a non dominant 1 would work?

Comment: You don't need to "pull" anything. MCP2551 Rx output is push-pull. It will be low on dominant and high on recessive state. If all you need is to detect network traffic then watching for 0 on Rx will work. Also low-pass filter will make it easier to process. Keep in mind that many CAN-based protocols have maintenance traffic that would keep bus busy.

Comment: It turns out that the MCP2551's RS pin which sets the slew rate can be pulled high which effectively disconnects the TX  from the network leaving the RX to still monitor the CAN activity. This can be used to save current and when monitored pulled low by a processor if CAN is detected. This works for my application.

Comment: Well, if the reduced reaction time is OK with you then sure, you can put the chip into standby. The result would be the same as connecting TX to Vcc and monitoring RX, except you will detect activity about 0.5 µS later